# Install ResetMusicAndVideosLibraries Configuration Profile

Tags: ios, configuration-profiles

The newest iOS Beta (7.6) says we need to install the ResetMusicAndVideosLibraries Configuration Profile to fix some bug.  How do I install that profile?  I tried dropping it into the Organizer window of XCode, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Questions about pre-release software (iOS7 in this case) are [off topic](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-7-and-os-x-mavericks-questions-ok?cb=1).

Comment: Your best bet is to check the [developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/) that track all the items you can / should / need to do for each specific beta build. We have intentionally decided to not field beta questions of all flavor and season on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can email ResetMusicAndVideosLibraries.mobileconfig on your iPhone and install it from the mail message.

After that:

1. Tap on Reset Library in Setting -> Music (it'll delete all your contents in Music and Video apps).
2. Restart your device.
3. Now you can reinsert your music and video using iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

The recent shipping versions of iOS can install profiles from email attachment, over the air from arbitrary webdav and http web servers, Dropbox, Apple Configurator, iTunes and Xcode.

My guess is the chain of trust for this particular profile is invalid or there are some other considerations relating to the beta nature of iOS 7. If you try some of the above methods and still can't install a configuration profile that you've been given to install, you might need to take things up with the source that generated the profile (in this case Apple developer relations).